# Highcharts: How to combine Column Range and Line Chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I basically want to just combine these two charts:

1) Column range: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

2) Basic line: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

Is this possible, considering that the first chart has a categorical Y-Axis?

I don't need to use categories, I only want the Y-Axis of the line chart. And the lines would be overlaid on top of the horizontal bars.

So both charts would be using the X-Axis time series, but only the line chart would be using the Y-Axis numbers.

Comment: Thanks for joining the Stack Overflow Community! Please review [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 0):

You can link both charts into one but you need to remember, that the columnrange chart is `inverted` and if you want to display line chart exactly like in this example (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic), you need to swap x values with y values of line series and both axis should have the same scale.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/jmmsyv9w/ - not inverted
http://jsfiddle.net/8unrzm1j/ - inverted